# CodeIgniter to Query WordPress blog

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, codeigniter

I am finally attempting my hand at some CodeIgniter, and I'm stuck currently.

## News Model

```
public function get_news($slug = FALSE){
    if($slug === FALSE){
        // if there is no slug specified, pull all records from the 'wp_posts' table
        $this->db->select('post_title, post_content, post_name');
        $this->db->where('post_status', 'published');
        $this->db->where('post_type', 'post');
        $this->db->order_by("post_date", "desc");
        $this->db->order_by("post_title", "asc");
        $query = $this->db->get('wp_posts');
        
        var_dump($query);
        
        // return the resulting array
        return $query->result_array();
    }else{
        // if it does exist, pull only the record(s) specified where column 'slug' = the parameter
        $this->db->select('post_title, post_content, post_name');
        $query = $this->db->get_where('wp_posts', array('post_name' => $slug));
        // return the resulting array
        return $query->row_array();
    }
}
```

## Controller

```
class News extends CI_Controller{
    
    public function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
        // located @ /application/models/news_model.php
        $this->load->model('news_model');   
    }
    
    // pull in all news items
    public function index(){
        $data['news'] = $this->news_model->get_news();
        // give the page a title
        $data['title'] = 'Articles Archive';
        $data['c_year'] = date('Y');
        // Load the header template
        $this->load->view('templates/header', $data);
        // Load the page
        $this->load->view('news/index', $data);
        // Load the footer template
        $this->load->view('templates/footer', $data);
    }
    
    // pull in only the news item(s) where the slug matches
    public function view($slug){
        $data['news_item'] = $this->news_model->get_news($slug);
        // give the page a title
        $data['title'] = $data['news_item']['title'];
        $data['c_year'] = date('Y');
        // Load the header template
        $this->load->view('templates/header', $data);
        // Load the page
        $this->load->view('news/view', $data);
        // Load the footer template
        $this->load->view('templates/footer', $data);
    }
        
}
```

Connection to the database is fine, but I am returning just the `show_404();` in my view because there are `no` records.

Running a similar query direct against the database does indeed return all my records.

Here is the results of the `var_dump`:

```
object(CI_DB_mysql_result)#18 (8) { 
   ["conn_id"]=> resource(3) of type (mysql link persistent) 
   ["result_id"]=> resource(4) of type (mysql result) 
   ["result_array"]=> array(0) { } 
   ["result_object"]=> array(0) { } 
   ["custom_result_object"]=> array(0) { } 
   ["current_row"]=> int(0) ["num_rows"]=> int(0)
   ["row_data"]=> NULL 
}
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: p.s.  my `routes` are proper... originally they followed the `News` tutorial right form the CodeIgnitor site

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change: `$this->db->where('post_status', 'published');`

To: `$this->db->where('post_status', 'publish');`

And the issue is cured...  been a long week...